# Word for reoccurring time things like "monday" or "the 15th" or "9 o'clock"

Tags: single-word-requests

What "monday", "the 15th" and "9 o'clock" have in common is that they repeat over and over. Every week has a monday, every month has a 15th and every day has a 9 o'clock. Is there a word for such a phenomenon?

I'm a programmer trying to document a feature of the syntax used to enter these types of things. A specific word would be really useful as I keep having to explain the concept every time I mention it.

So if a specific and unique point in time could be signified by "date" or "datetime" then what would I call these specific but reoccurring points in time?

Comment: Could you construct an example sentence showing how you would hope to use this word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

[Recurrent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recurrent) - returning or happening time after time

Or

[Periodic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodic) - occurring or recurring at regular intervals

In a programming context, I'd favor "periodic".

Comment: I like periodic

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to this. First is the "start time." Second is the recurrence interval. Is that correct?

For #1, I consider words like: Date-Time-Group (DTG), Epoch, Start, Instantiation
For #2, I'd consider: Frequency, Interval, Repetition Interval, Rate, Repetitiveness

Comment: Na its all one question. There is no start time, if something happens on monday it is on every monday that has ever been and ever will be.